# Failed to cast variant value "2023-04-30" to REAL

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dataframe (temp_df) in python where the "Month" column is datetime.date.

```
[datetime.date(2020, 1, 31), datetime.date(2020, 2, 29),
   datetime.date(2020, 3, 31), datetime.date(2020, 4, 30),
   datetime.date(2020, 5, 31), ...]
```

Also, I have a specific SQL table where the Month column is DATE

```
ctx.cursor().execute(
"CREATE or REPLACE TABLE DummyTable "
"(\"Company Name\" varchar(255), \"Month\" Date, ...
```

I was following the documentation:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#date-and-timestamp-support

When I try to insert data into the table, using:

```
success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(conn=ctx, df=temp, table_name='DummyTable'.upper(), schema=STAGING_SCHEMA.upper(), database=STAGING_DB.upper())
```

I get the following error:

**100071 (22000): Failed to cast variant value "2023-04-30" to REAL**

Comment: As far as I can see, your code should work, and there should not be casting to 'REAL' if your target column is 'DATE'. Are you sure that the database and schema names in your `write_pandas` command are the same you use for creating connection - ctx? It can be that you try to use a table in a different db/schema to insert your data.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am sure of that. 
Before creating the DummyTable I used:

ctx.cursor().execute("USE DATABASE "+STAGING_DB)
ctx.cursor().execute("USE SCHEMA "+STAGING_SCHEMA)

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I believe your `CREATE or REPLACE TABLE` was executed successfully before the script fails. Can you run `desc table DUMMYTABLE;` and see if your Month column has actually type - DATE? btw, do you have any other columns with the "real" type?